# Get attribute of all list items and add them to input

Tags: javascript

I have a list like this:

```
<ul class="draggable">
    <li data-bullet="1"> item 1</li>
    <li data-bullet="2"> item 2</li>
    <li data-bullet="3"> item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Using javascript, how do I grab all the list item attributes `data-bullet` and insert them into the value of an input (separated by a comma):

```
<input id="insertme" type="hidden" name="bullet" value="">
```

So the end result will be:

```
<input id="insertme" type="hidden" name="bullet" value="1,2,3">
```

I know how to get individual list items but can't get my head around how to get them all and insert them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, A pure javascript solution

Try to use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) at this context,

```
var res = "";
[].forEach.bind(document.querySelectorAll(
   '.draggable > li[data-bullet]'),function(itm, i){
  res += ((i) ? ":" : "") + itm.dataset.bullet;
})();

document.getElementById("insertme").value = res;
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ljs8496/)

Or the less complex and a readable version would be,

```
var elemArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.draggable > li[data-bullet]')),
    res ="";
elemArray.forEach(function(){
 res += ((i) ? ":" : "") + itm.dataset.bullet;
});
document.getElementById("insertme").value = res;
```

---

As per your new requirement, you can accomplish your task by,

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent(); 
  parent.closest(".draggable").next(":text").val(parent.siblings("li").addBack().map(function(){
    return $(this).data("bullet")
  }).get().join(":"));
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ljs8496/4/)

Comment: This is very nice, thank you. I have one final question. How do I target the input if it doesn't have an ID. See the edit I made to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8Ljs8496/2/ -- the code is triggered when user clicks the button. In jQuery, I would do something like jQuery(this).parent().parent().next...

Comment: This is in every way **exactly** what I am looking for. Although I can't seem to make it work in my own code. Please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/h2qnucpg/4/ Drag the list item and see the code being triggered (check the bottom of the JS script to find the function for it). Is it possible to implement this very solution there that *actually works*? I will bounty this question with 50 points when eligible because I'm asking you more than initially requested.

Comment: @GaryWoods Reps doesn't matter man. I am here to gain knowledge not reps. :) we solved the issue that you have asked initially, If you want to solve your further issues, do not hesitate to ask a new question. So that you would get more expert's attention on that. Also your new question will help other people who has exact problem like you. :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var allBullets = [];
$(".draggable li").each(function(){
 allBullets.push($(this).attr("data-bullet"));
});
$("#insertme").val(allBullets.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find elements and then map it using [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method. For example (ES6 syntax):

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable li');
const result = [...items].map(el => el.getAttribute('data-bullet')).join();
document.getElementById('insertme').value = result;
```

ES5 analogy:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable li');
var result = [].slice.call(items).map(function(el) {
    return el.getAttribute('data-bullet');
}).join();
document.getElementById('insertme').value = result;
```